# Undo and Redo Functionality in android drawing app using Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

i'm working on a project where i create mirror of drawing. my main logic is working fine.Only thing causing Problem is Redo and undo functionality.
i have searched a lot. implement may methods but couldn't get success. Following is my Drawing Class.

DrawingView.java

```
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context=context;
    setupDrawing();


}

//setup drawing
private void setupDrawing(){

    //prepare for drawing and setup paint stroke properties
    brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
    lastBrushSize = brushSize;
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPath1 = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

//size assigned to view
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {


    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    width=w;
    height=h;
    Log.d("width,height", w + " , " + h);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);




}

//draw the view - will be called after touch event
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    for (Path p : paths){canvas.drawPath(p, drawPaint);}
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    Log.i("OnDRAWING", "REACH ON DRAW");
    /*canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath1, drawPaint);*/






}

//register user touches as drawing action
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {



    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    //respond to down, move and up events
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        drawPath.reset();
        undonePaths.clear();
        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
        undonePaths.clear();



        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);


        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);// commit the path to our offscreen
        paths.add(drawPath);
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        drawPath.reset();

        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath1, drawPaint);
        drawPath1.reset();

        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    //redraw
    invalidate();
    return true;

}
```

What i am missing here?
Any suggestions/ideas/examples which is the best way to implement this kind of functionality on my project?

Answer (score 1):

Canvas drawing is sort of hierarchal in that drawing happens in the order that you do them.

So all drawing should be done in `onDraw` and only here.

Your draw events should be pushed on a draw stack. You do not store a canvas. You just store the operations that are supposed to happen when the drawing eventually occurs (coordinates, width, and color of a path for example).

An "undo" operation can be done by popping from the drawing stack and pushing the event to a "redo" stack.  The "redo" event can be done by popping from the "redo" stack and pushing back on to the "drawing" stack.

In `onDraw` method of your View, just scan through the drawing events and draw on the canvas.

EDIT:

The `onDraw()` method would just iterate through your drawing operations.  So first you could have an `interface` called `DrawEvent` like so:

```
public interface DrawEvent {
   void draw(Canvas c);
}
```

Then in your View class have your collection of `DrawEvents` and iterate through them in `onDraw(Canvas c)`.

```
public class MyView extends View {
    Deque<DrawEvent> drawEvents = new LinkedList<DrawEvent>();

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
       for (DrawEvent e : drawEvents) {
           e.draw(c);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. i understand the flow.  can you tell me what should i write in ondraw. its little confusing for me. i will appreciate any help.

Comment: I edited it to show how the onDraw method would work.  The point I'm trying to get across is you can't save or use the Canvas outside the `onDraw` or `draw` methods of a View.  You have to store the events and instructions on how to draw and keep them in order.

Comment: i was adding path to list before. now as i implement an interface i am confused where to add and what to add to drawEvents.

Comment: It's an Interface so you create classes that do their own drawing implementations.  A line event may contain a Path and a Paint and draw the Path. A circle event may contain just a Paint and radius.  You use Interfaces so you can just inject classes that implement "DrawEvents" without having to modify the code of the View.